# Web API Route with optional prefix-- how to handle?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm implementing a REST API using ASP.NET's Web API framework.  My API routes have the typical format,

```
$BASE_URI/api/resource1...
$BASE_URI/api/resource2...
$BASE_URI/api/resource3...
```

etc.  Most (if not all) routes also have an optional prefix with an ID:

```
$BASE_URI/api/prefix/{id}/resource1...
$BASE_URI/api/prefix/{id}/resource2...
$BASE_URI/api/prefix/{id}/resource3...
```

When the prefix is not supplied, the API is supposed to use a default value (like 0) and the response does not require authorization.  When the prefix *is* supplied, the request must be authorized.

The prefix gets handled in the *same way* every time (but obviously the different resources get handled differently).  Is there a way for me to parse the `prefix` component of the route separately, and then handle the route suffix normally?  I am trying to avoid the situation where I have duplicate route entries for *every* resource, where the only difference is the prefix handling.

If you think this is bad design, I'd like to hear about that too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define two separate routes, there's no other way around.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApiWithPrefix",
    routeTemplate: "api/prefix/{prefixId}/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Web API 2, below is a guide to Attribute Routing, otherwise there is no simple work around.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2